# Dealing with ownership

Tags: ownership

How would I change the ownership of a recently made file to root user ownership from its original owner? Every time I type in the following (below), I get a message saying that  it can't change the ownership.

For Example:

```
touch myfile
chown root myfile
```

Comment: Is the file on an NTFS partition?

Comment: You need `sudo`  before `chmod`

Comment: Are you trying to change the ownership of the file as a "normal", unprivileged user? Only the privileged `root` user is allowed to change file ownerships. To execute a command with privileged permissions, you can use `sudo` ("*s*witch *u*ser and *do*" - in this case, "switch to root and do").

Answer (score 3):

Unprivileged user can't change ownership of a file. To do so, you must be a privileged user or use `sudo` before `chown` command. Consider that you must be sudoer to issue `sudo`.

```
touch myfile
sudo chown root myfile
```